# Centering and \MakeUppercase with linebreaks

Tags: macros, errors, line-breaking, capitalization

I wish to make the list of authors show up as centered, uppercase and listed vertically on my titlepage. My documentclass contains a section like this

```
\begin{center}
...
\renewcommand{\and}{\\}\MakeUppercase{\@author}
...
\end{center}
```

but this particular combination or linebreaks, MakeUppercase and centering causes an error; `\@icentercr doesn't match its definition`

A minimal example would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytext}{Foo \\ Bar}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \MakeUppercase{\mytext}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TeX command `\uppercase` works without error:

```
\uppercase{Foo \\ Bar}
```

Output is:

> FOO
>
> BAR

If the LaTeX command would work, I would prefer it over a TeX command, but as it doesn't work here we could go deeper to a TeX command. Perhaps you are interested in the [`textcase`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package, which also helps to overcome some case-changing problems.

Using `textcase` the line break can be protected;

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\and}{\NoCaseChange{\\}}
\MakeTextUppercase{\@author}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I suppose i should have mentioned uppercase as well. For a fixed text it works fine, but it won't work for a text defined in a command, i.e. `\uppercase{\@author}` does nothing.

Comment: I'm voting this up as the answer, but not because of `\uppercase`, but the `textcase` package. I will edit your answer to include the working code.

Comment: @Miakael: Good that `textcase` helped. I just used `\uppercase` to fix the minimal example. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

While Stefan Kottwitzs answer does correct the problem, it incorrectly diagnoses it. The issue isn't one with upper or lower case: it's that the definition of `\\`, normally robust, is redefined by the `\centering` macro to something fragile. Note that the following MWE works just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytext}{Foo \protect\\ Bar}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \MakeUppercase{\mytext}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Presumably the TeX `\uppercase` macro doesn't require robust arguments, while `\MakeUppercase` does.