# LaTeX package "titling", titles with hard line breaks, and \MakeUpperCase

Tags: line-breaking, titles, titling

I have a document with a title that is spread over several lines using hard line breaks. To configure the title formatting, I use the `titling` package with code adapted from its documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}

\title{Higgelty Pigglety Pop! \\ or \\ There Must Be More to Life}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

…and it works perfectly.

I now want the title additionally to be in all caps and therefore change the `\pretitle` command:

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
```

…and I get the following error message:

```
! Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def

l.12 \maketitle
```

This only happens with a title that includes hard line breaks.

What does this error message mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: If that's your actual title then (a) that's awesome, and (b) you might want to be consistent with *-elty* vs *-lety* (that is, either *Higglety Pigglety* or *Higgelty Piggelty*; I might suggest the latter unless you're trying to invoke images of piglets anyway).

Comment: @WChargin, no its not, I just like [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Higglety-Pigglety-There-Must-More/dp/0064430219). :) And you're right, it's actually Higglety Pigglety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split the title at `\\` and apply `\MakeUppercase` to each chunk:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{\DoUppercase{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\DoUppercase[1]{\Do@Uppercase#1\\\@nil}
\def\Do@Uppercase#1\\#2\@nil{%
  \MakeUppercase{#1}%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \\\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\Do@Uppercase#2\@nil}%
}
\makeatother

\title{Higgelty Pigglety Pop! \\ or \\ There Must Be More to Life}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This is obtained by redefining `\title` to store `\DoUppercase{<title>}` in `\@title` rather than just the title.

You can't use the vertical spacing optional argument to `\\`, though.

[image]

If you want to support also `\\[3pt]` or whatever, then it is possible with `l3regex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\@title{\DoUppercase{#1}}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DoUppercase}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \\ }
  % Add \MakeUppercase{ at the beginning and } at end
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { (.*) }
   { \c{MakeUppercase}\cB\{\1\cE\}} \l_tmpa_tl
  % change \\[...] into }\\[...]\MakeUppercase{
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \u{l_tmpb_tl}\[(.*?)\] }
   { \cE\}\u{l_tmpb_tl}\[\1\]\c{MakeUppercase}\cB\{ }
   \l_tmpa_tl
  % change \\ into }\\\MakeUppercase{
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \u{l_tmpb_tl}([^\[]) }
   { \cE\}\u{l_tmpb_tl}\c{MakeUppercase}\cB\{\1 }
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{Higgelty Pigglety Pop! \\[3pt] or \\ There Must Be More to Life}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! – Just out of interest: The stuff that "titling" does could all as well be implemented using `\makeatletter`, correct? Or rather, "titling" uses `\makeatletter` internally to plug in that pre- and post-code?

Comment: @A.Donda Not sure what you mean; `\makeatletter` is used in order to access to “private macros”.

Comment: OK, this just proves that I have only the most superficial understanding of the inner workings of TeX/LaTeX. :-)

Comment: @egreg `expl3`-based version (essentially `\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\xdef\@title{\tl_upper_case:n{#1}}}` or similar)?

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, no. If I use `\'{e}` inside the title, the `e` is not uppercased. How I wished that Knuth had started providing an “all caps” font instead of slanted type.

Comment: @egreg Far enough: currently handling this sort of thing is this is an open question

Comment: @JosephWright So, such problem is in general an open question. Me too, I have a feeling that this problem and incomplete solutions are a bit weird. What do you think about the possibility of a command like \MakeUppercase which would display all the letters upper-cased, but without such tricky restrictions as protecting \\ in `center` or having to write a special implementation looking for a lot of special cases? Is it a fault of \MakeUppercase? Or perhaps, it's a fault of the definition of `center`, `\centering` etc. I'm just thinking about the most clean way to solve such problem in theory...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with `stringstrings`.  The reason it does not work directly with `\MakeUppercase` is that the argument of the title contains the macro `\\`.  I am presuming that the  `\MakeUppercase` macro works only or regular expressions without macros.  In general the `stringstrings` package has the same limitations, but it does have provisions for limited exceptions.

What the logic does is tell `stringstrings` to pre-encode each `\\` into a ASCII-encoded sequence.  It then can operate `\caseupper` on this sequence using its `[e]` encoded mode (which does not print out an immediate result, instead storing it in the expanded macro `\thestring`).  The `\retokenize` macro is needed to process `\thestring`, reconverting each ASCII-encoded `\\` back into the LaTeX macro `\\`.

In the course of answering this question, a bug was discovered in the `stringstrings` package which required the following patch.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
% BUG FIX
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@retokenizechar}{{~}}{{\ }}
\makeatother
```

However...

UPDATE: The `stringstrings` package was upgraded to V1.23 on 2 FEB 2015, to resolve this bug.  Here is the revised MWE, without the need for a patch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling,stringstrings}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries%
\encodetoken{\\}\caseupper[e]%
}
\posttitle{\retokenize{\thestring}%
\thestring\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}

\title{Higgelty Pigglety Pop!\\or\\There Must Be More to Life}

%Now Works for string without \\
%\title{Higgelty Pigglety Pop! or There Must Be More to Life}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain why the `\MakeUppercase` would not work

Comment: @daleif  Thanks.  I have added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you! – but: this appears to only work well with this specific manually line-broken title. If I remove the `\\` from the title, I get the title automatically broken like this: 1st line "HIGGELTY PIG-", 2nd line "GLETY POP! OR THERE MUST BE MORE TO LIFE". The second is also no longer properly centered.

Comment: Moreover, if I use your solution in the context of another document that loads many more packages, it get a title that has the letters `.”0152.` inserted at every whitespace location.

Comment: @A.Donda I commend the use of egreg's solution, but I wanted to post a repaired version that I think should also work.  It required a bug-fix patch to `stringstrings`.

Comment: @A.Donda The `stringstrings` package has been updated to V1.23 on 2 FEB 2015 to repair the bug discovered in the course of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to load David Carlisle [textcase](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package with the option `overload`. Then you just put the `\\`-macro into a `\NoCaseChange{}`, i.e.

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

...
...

\title{Higglety, Pigglety Pop!\NoCaseChange{\\}or\NoCaseChange{\\} 
      There must be more to life}
```

Comment: I didn't say this explicitly, but the idea is not to have to make any changes to the title definition itself, but to have some preamble code that does the styling. Otherwise, I could just write the title in all-caps manually.

Comment: @A.Donda OK. But I do not see the big difference between putting in ` \\\` and `\NoCaseChange{\\}` in `\title{}`. The ` \\\` is added to the `\title`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

This problem arises because `\\` is redefined in the `center` environment to something [fragile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736), which `\MakeUppercase` doesn't like (see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106373/14635)).  The simplest way to get this title to work is to `\protect` the `\\`:

```
\title{Higgelty Pigglety Pop! \protect\\ or \protect\\ There Must Be More to Life}
```

Comment: Will this break the re-defined `\\\` somehow, or will it work just the same way?

Comment: BTW, this problem feels a bit weird. What do you think about the possibility of a command like \MakeUppercase which would display all the letters upper-cased, but without such tricky restrictions as \protecting \\ when centering. Perhaps, it's a fault of the definition of `center`, `\centering` etc., and a fix there could be imagined ? So that it all works more cleanly. I'm just thinking about the most clean way to solve such problem in theory...