# Raggedright and uppercase title with \\ gives error

Tags: titles, capitalization

The following code gives this error:

```
! Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def 

l.18 \maketitle

?
```

The goal is to create a title like

```
FOO BAR
BAZ FOO FOO
BARBAZ FOO
```

from

```
\title{Foo bar\\baz foo foo\\barbaz foo}
```

so I can control the line breaks and get the text upper case. How can I get the code to work?

Here is the faulty code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Hello with\\crlf}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
    \raggedright
    {\MakeUppercase{\@title} \par}%
  \end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure to have already seen a very similar question

Comment: Can http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226166/latex-package-titling-titles-with-hard-line-breaks-and-makeuppercase be considered as duplicate?

Comment: `! Use of ..... doesn't match its definition` is latex-speak for `you forgot to use \protect`