# \uppercase-style commands: Line breaks AND within braces

Tags: capitalization, grouping

[This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/centering-and-makeuppercase-with-linebreaks) describes how to make all capital commands which can handle newlines,
using the `\uppercase` command.

[This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35680/uppercase-in-newcommand) describes how to make all capital commands which can handle curly braces.

How would I perform both?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\Title}  {Uppercase Instructions}
\newcommand{\Author} {Latex Newb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\MakeUppercase{%
\Title\protect\\
Written By:\protect\\
\Author

\vspace*{\fill}

At:\protect\\
University of Colleges
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Alright, per H Oberdiek,

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\Title}  {Uppercase Instructions}
\newcommand{\Author} {Latex Newb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\uppercase{%
\MakeUppercase{\Title}\\
Written By:\\
\MakeUppercase{\Author}

\vspace*{\fill}

At:\\
University of Colleges
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I believe using the `\uppercase` command throughout
while using the `\MakeUppercase` command around commands
will help a portion of people looking for added flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know, what you mean with braces. The primitive `\uppercase` only converts direct tokens and does not expand macros. Thus, the letters in `\Title` and `\Author` are hidden. The LaTeX macro `\MakeUppercase` expands the argument to expose the letters in macros. But here, it breaks on the fragile `\\`, which needs protection:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\Title}  {Uppercase Instructions}
\newcommand{\Author} {Latex Newb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\MakeUppercase{%
\Title\protect\\
Written By:\protect\\
\Author}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

LaTeX's `\MakeUppercase` does not work with "long" arguments containing empty lines or `\par` tokens. Instead of the empty lines `\endgraf` can be used:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand{\Title}  {Uppercase Instructions}
\newcommand{\Author} {Latex Newb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\MakeUppercase{%
\Title\protect\\
Written By:\protect\\
\Author
\endgraf
\vspace*{\fill}
\endgraf
At:\protect\\
University of Colleges}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright - is it possible to \renewcommand{\\}{\protect\\} within the bounds of the \MakeUppercase group?

Comment: Also, what if I want to use newlines?

Comment: MWE code updated to pursue this question.

Comment: @kando `\newline` is robust.

Comment: @kando Are you sure, you want to have such an ugly title page by converting all to upper case? AFAIK, this kind of emphasis comes from the time of mechanical typewriters with a limited set of font faces (usually just one). Nowadays, there are bold fonts, larger font sizes, ...

Comment: (I agree with your assessment about caps; however, the template is school enforced.)

Comment: Alright - answer posted below. What do you think of the hybrid approach?  I can delete after - I just didn't know where to dump the code.

Comment: @kando (You can edit your question.) I can't comment, because I do not know about the requirements of your school.